Salesforce Multipart bulk Api
Endpoint :- org_url/services/data/v58.0/jobs/ingest/
header
Method :- POST
Content-Type :- multipart/form-data; boundary="BOUNDARY"
Accept :- application/json

Body :-
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="job"

{
  "object":"Contact",
  "contentType":"CSV",
  "operation": "insert",
  "lineEnding" : "LF"
}

--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="content"

FirstName,LastName,MailingCity
Astro,Nomical,San Francisco
Hootie,McOwl,San Francisco
Appy,Camper,San Francisco
Earnie,Badger,San Francisco
--BOUNDARY--

in JSON
working fine at workbench, but getting "Mixed content error: cannot send request.
The request has been blocked because it requested an insecure HTTP resource." in postman
Can anyone the reason of error and how to slove it

You should provide the protocol used (http:// or https:// or else) as the error message seems related to this. Sometimes hiding too much information prevent users from helping you.

There can be multiple reasons for this.

First, check your credentials and make sure your
postman is connected with Salesforce.
If everything is correct and still getting errors, then check your Postman Agent, it should be "Desktop Agent", if you have selected other than this then you may get this error because others have limitations.

